# Reading QR Code

Tags: objective-c, ios, time-limit-exceeded

What I need to accomplish is matching the QR code to the one I have created. This code works, except it takes at least 30 seconds to verify that it has matched my QR Code. How can I make it faster?

#### QRCodeVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface QRCodeVC : UIViewController <AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate> {

NSTimer *timer;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewPreview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageCheckmark;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wrongQRCodeLabel;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSString *messageString;

@end
```

#### QRCodeVC.m

```
#import "QRCodeVC.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface QRCodeVC ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *videoPreviewLayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isReading;

-(BOOL)startReading;
-(void)stopReading;
-(void)loadBeepSound;

@end

@implementation QRCodeVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
}

self.imageCheckmark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];

// Initially make the captureSession object nil.
_captureSession = nil;

// Set the initial value of the flag to NO.
_isReading = NO;

// Begin loading the sound effect so to have it ready for playback when it's needed.
[self loadBeepSound];

self.viewPreview.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
self.viewPreview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];

// Navigation Bar Attibutes
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar
 setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

if (!_isReading) {
    // This is the case where the app should read a QR code when the start button is tapped.
    if ([self startReading]) {

    }
}
else{
    // In this case the app is currently reading a QR code and it should stop doing so.
    [self stopReading];
}

// Set to the flag the exact opposite value of the one that currently has.
_isReading = !_isReading;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Private method implementation

- (BOOL)startReading {
NSError *error;

// Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video
// as the media type parameter.
AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

// Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

if (!input) {
    // If any error occurs, simply log the description of it and don't continue any more.
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
}

// Initialize the captureSession object.
_captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
// Set the input device on the capture session.
[_captureSession addInput:input];


// Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
[_captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput];

// Create a new serial dispatch queue.
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue;
dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];

// Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
_videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
[_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_viewPreview.layer.bounds];
[_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];


self.messageString = AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode;

// Start video capture.
[_captureSession startRunning];

return YES;
}


-(void)stopReading{

//    self.imageCheckmark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark_RA"];

// Stop video capture and make the capture session object nil.
[_captureSession stopRunning];
_captureSession = nil;

/*
 // Remove the video preview layer from the viewPreview view's layer.
 [_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
 */
}


-(void)loadBeepSound{
// Get the path to the beep.mp3 file and convert it to a NSURL object.
NSString *beepFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *beepURL = [NSURL URLWithString:beepFilePath];

NSError *error;

// Initialize the audio player object using the NSURL object previously set.
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:beepURL error:&error];
if (error) {
    // If the audio player cannot be initialized then log a message.
    NSLog(@"Could not play beep file.");
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    // If the audio player was successfully initialized then load it in memory.
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}
}


#pragma mark - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate method implementation

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {








// It is very slow from here





// Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {
    // Get the metadata object.
    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]) {

        NSString *scanResult = [metadataObj stringValue];

        if ([scanResult isEqualToString:@"myQRCode"]) {

            self.imageCheckmark.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark_RA"];


            [[PFUser currentUser] incrementKey:@"Points" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded) {
                    NSLog(@"The object has been saved.");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"There was a problem");
                }
            }];


             {
            // }

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations!" message:@"1 point has been added to your account" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes!" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertView show];

            NSLog(@"Correct QR Code!");

        } else {

            self.wrongQRCodeLabel.text = @"Wrong QR Code!";
            NSLog(@"Wrong QR Code!");

        }

        NSLog(@"%@", scanResult);






// To here







        // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text,
        // stop reading and change the bar button item's title and the flag's value.
        // Everything is done on the main thread

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

        _isReading = NO;

        // If the audio player is not nil, then play the sound effect.
        if (_audioPlayer) {
            [_audioPlayer play];
        }
    }
}
}

- (void) loading {
    }

@end
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked where the slowdown is? Is it in the reading? Comparing? It also wouldn't hurt to indent your code a bit better, it's hard to follow some of it as it stands.

Comment: Start with a benchmark.  Run it in Instruments.

Comment: How do you benchmark where the slowdown is? @EBrown

Comment: @PeterSchultz I would start by timing each section of execution to get an idea for where the time starts stacking up.

Comment: Xcode comes with an application called "Instruments".  Use that.  Find out what is using the most time.

Comment: I edited the code to show where the hidden bugs and time usage takes place @nhgrif

Comment: Your edit didn't tell me (or anyone else familiar with AVCaptureSession stuff) anything that we didn't already know.  You need [data like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/Art/Time_Profiler_instrument.png) demonstrating what methods are being called how many times and using what percentage of the processor's time.  Without that, there's no point addressing any of your performance concerns.

Answer (score 3):

#### Indent your code.

Massive swaths of your code have almost no indention to them at all.  Everything is stuck to the left edge, which makes it impossible to distinguish where one method ends and the next one begins (at a glance).

Everything inside a set of curly braces should be indented one level greater than the stuff immediately outside those braces.

```
- (void)someMethod {
    if (someCondition) {
        for (Foo *foo in arrayOfFoos) {
            // this is an example of proper indentation
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Don't abuse vertical white space.

Vertical white space is a great way of visually separating chunks of code that into groupings that go together logically.  For example, a few lines of declaration code can be grouped together following by an empty line.  This is a quick visual cue that helps readers organize your code in their mind.

But anything more than a single blank line is almost always over kill.  If you need to draw extra attention to lines, do so with comments, multiline comment blocks, or your best bet, `#pragma mark` commentary.

Otherwise, you're just exercising people's scroll finger.

---

#### Don't leave completely empty methods in your code.

> ```
> - (void) loading {
>     }
> ```

Why is this here?

Anyone maintaining this code will ask this, and given the lack of commentary about it, they will delete it (I'm currently working in a project that is littered with hundreds of empty methods like this).

If there's a particularly good reason why this empty method needs to stay, leave a comment within the method body (so it's no longer technically empty) explaining why it needs to stay.  Otherwise, remove it now.

If you don't remove it or comment it, someone maintaining the code will remove it.  And if we're writing good code, we're doing everything we can to make the maintainer's job as easy as possible.  Part of this includes removing things we know a maintainer would logically remove (or leaving a comment to the maintainer indicating why it shouldn't be removed).

---

#### Methods that only call super are the same as nothing.

> ```
> - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
> [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
> // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
> ```

If you're only calling `super`, you don't need to implement the method at all.

I realize this is stub code that Xcode automatically generates any time you create a view controller subclass, but at the end of the day, it's still just clutter code that a good maintainer will eventually delete anyway, so let's take care of that now.

---

#### Don't leave in commented out code.

[You should be using some form of source control](http://importblogkit.com/2015/04/source-control/).  (Hint: Xcode has built-in git support and will create repos for you.)  This will keep track of your code changes, so if you ever need to go back in time and look at code that used to be in your project, you can do that using source control.

If you need code that is only run for debug builds, you can do things like use preprocessor macros to conditionally include the code:

```
#if DEBUG
    [self executeSomeDebugModeOnlyMethod];
#endif
```

If it's not code that you only intend to include for particular builds, you should simply remove it for all the reasons mentioned above when I discussed the trouble of leaving in empty methods.  Ultimately, it just looks like clutter to the maintainer who will probably just delete it.

---

#### Don't use `UIAlertView`.

`UIAlertView` will be deprecated as of iOS 9.  `UIAlertController` was introduced as of iOS 8.  If your code doesn't support iOS 8, your app won't be approved on the app store.  The window for apps that don't support iOS 9 will probably be closing in about 6 months from now.

If you need to support iOS versions before iOS 8, you need to implement some conditional code which should always use `UIAlertController` when it's available, and when it's not, use `UIAlertView`.

---

#### On using literals...

As a rule, you shouldn't be using literal numbers or strings except when initializing constants that you'll be reusing later.

But when you do use literals, whether your using magic numbers or defining values, use the value you literally need.

> ```
> (1.0/2.0)
> ```

Why can't we just write this as:

```
0.5
```

---

#### Use properties.  Or don't.

You've created this property:

> ```
> @property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
> ```

Yet you repeatedly access the backing variable directly:

> ```
> _audioPlayer
> ```

Rather than going through the accessors:

```
self.audioPlayer
```

If you're going to create a property, use the accessors.  If you're not going to use the accessors, don't create it as a property--just create it as an instance variable.